# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstOrFail()

Tags: laravel, webshop

I tried to follow but still got the error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate \ Database \ Query \ Builder ::
>   firstOrFail()

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Query Builder does not have the `firstOrFail();` method, it's only available to Eloquent models, for example if `tbl_product` was a `Product` model then it would be:

```
  $product_info = Product::where('product_id', $productId)->firstOrFail();
```

If you want to use Query Builder, then you could do the following:

```
 $product_info = DB::table('tbl_product')->where('product_id', $productId)->first();

    if ($product_info === null)
        throw \Exception('Product not found');
```

Answer (score -1):

In Eloquent model you have to use `firstOrFail` method

```
$product_info = Product::where('product_id'=>$productId)->firstOrFail();
```

Or you have to use

```
$product_info = Product::where('product_id'=>$productId)->first();
```